# Limitations for Option Strings in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Are there limitations for strings used for options? I'm tyring to use the Transient API and when I inlude a string of url in the transient name, it does not save the data. I'm not sure if it is due to a character length or illegual characters.

```
$url = 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php+wordpress+wordpress-plugin';
$strTransient = 'sample_transient_' . $url;
$key = 'sample_transient';
$html = get_transient($strTransient);   
if( false === $html ) {
    echo 'cache is not used: ' . $strTransient . '<br />';      
    $html = wp_remote_get($url);    
    $html = $html['body'];  
    $savehtml = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), $html, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($key))));
    set_transient($strTransient, $savehtml, 60 );
} else {
    echo 'cache is used. <br />';
    $html = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), base64_decode($html), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($key)));  
}
print_r($html);
```

Thanks in advance.

[Edit]

It seems to be due to the character length.

```
$transientkey = 'verylongstring_verylongstring_verylongstring_verylongstring_verylongstring_verylongstring_verylongstring'; // <-- fails
// $transientkey = 'shortstring';   // <-- okay

$data = get_transient($transientkey);   
if( false === $data ) {
    echo 'transient is not saved: ' . $transientkey . '<br />';     
    $data = 'hello world!';
    echo 'now saving the data.<br />';
    set_transient($transientkey, $data, 60 );
} else {
    echo 'transient is used. <br />';
}
print_r($data);
```

So where can I find the exact information about the limitations for option keys? I could not find it in the core. This is the comment for `set_transient()`

**wp-includes/option.php**

```
/**
 * Set/update the value of a transient.
 *
 * You do not need to serialize values. If the value needs to be serialized, then
 * it will be serialized before it is set.
 *
 * @since 2.8.0
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Transient
 *
 * @uses apply_filters() Calls 'pre_set_transient_$transient' hook to allow overwriting the
 *  transient value to be stored.
 * @uses do_action() Calls 'set_transient_$transient' and 'setted_transient' hooks on success.
 *
 * @param string $transient Transient name. Expected to not be SQL-escaped.
 * @param mixed $value Transient value. Expected to not be SQL-escaped.
 * @param int $expiration Time until expiration in seconds, default 0
 * @return bool False if value was not set and true if value was set.
 */
```

Also any suggestion to identify a url as a transient key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation says](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/set_transient) the transient name is "*Expected to not be SQL-escaped. Should be 45 characters or less in length.*"

Looking at the table structure in Wordpress 3.4.1:

```
mysql> desc wp_options;
+--------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| option_id    | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| option_name  | varchar(64)         | NO   | UNI |         |                |
| option_value | longtext            | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| autoload     | varchar(20)         | NO   |     | yes     |                |
+--------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

So the `option_name` can be no longer than 64 characters, but the `data` can be as large as 2<sup>32</sup> bytes (~4GB).  `set_transient` ultimately calls `add/update_option` which can have an option name up to 64 characters long, but since the transient works in a special way, `45` is the longest value you should use.

EDIT:

From looking at the WP code, the reason the transient name is restricted to 45 characters per the reference guide is because the code does this:

```
$transient_timeout = '_transient_timeout_' . $transient;
//...
add_option( $transient_timeout, time() + $expiration, '', 'no' );
```

So if you pass `hello` as the transient, it will add an option called `_transient_timeout_hello`.  Given that: `45 + strlen('_transient_timeout_') === 64` and 64 is the maximum varchar length of the option name field in the WP options table.

Comment: Thanks for the information. What would you suggest to identify a url to save it as a transient key?

Comment: Since a SHA-1 hash in hex format will be 40 chars, you could pass the URL to sha1 beforehand.  As long as you don't need to reverse it that should work.

Comment: The key length limit was extended from `45` characters to `172` characters (see https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/13310), so it's no longer a concern in most cases.